# How can I use MyPy to overload the __init__ method to adjust a getter's return value?

Tags: python, mypy

Let's say I have a class like this (pseudo-code, please ignore the odd db structure):

```
class Blog():
    title = StringProperty()
    comments = StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

I want to type check `StringProperty` such that `Blog().title` returns a `str` type, and `Blog().comments` returns a `List[str]` type. MyPy mentions that something like this is possible by [dynamically typing the `__init__`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#restricted-methods-in-generic-classes) method.

Here's what I've tried:

```
U = TypeVar('U', bound=StringProperty)
V = TypeVar('V', bound=StringProperty)

class StringProperty(Property[T]):
    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[U], repeated: Literal[False]=False, **kwargs) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[V], repeated: Literal[True]=True, **kwargs) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self: StringProperty[U], instance, cls) -> str: ...
    
    @overload
    def __get__(self: StringProperty[V], instance, cls) -> List[str]: ...
    
    def __set__(self, instance, value: Optional[Union[str, List[str]]]) -> None: ...
```

However, this throws an error that the second `__get__` type signature will never be matched. How can I set MyPy to know the return value of the `StringProperty.__get__` method dynamically by whether the `repeated` property is `True` or `False`?

Comment: What makes a list-valued property a `StringProperty`? I would just define `StringListProperty` instead.

Comment: `mypy` can't make typing distinctions about runtime properties. Statically, *both* your definitions take a `StringProperty` as its first argument. There's nothing at compile time that says whether `__get__` will return a `str` or a `List[str]`, so `mypy` assumes the first will always apply.

Comment: @chepner edited for clarity - wouldn't `mypy` be able to tell whether `__get__` is operating on `StringProperty[U]` or `StringProperty[V]` based on whether `repeated` is `True` or `False` in the `__init__` method?

Comment: No. Where it's used, it's just a variable with no known compile-time value.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` can be overloaded. `self` will become the given type.

`TypeVar` needs to become some kind of real type during type analysis. It can't stay as `T` or `U` or `V`. It must be filled in with a type like `str` or `Literal["foo"]`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Literal, Generic

_GetReturnT = TypeVar('_GetReturnT', str, list[str], str | list[str])

class StringProperty(Generic[_GetReturnT]):
    
    # Handles the default value case too.
    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[str], repeated: Literal[False]=False, **kwargs) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[list[str]], repeated: Literal[True], **kwargs) -> None: ...
    
    # Callers won't always pass a literal bool right at the call site. The bool
    # could come from somewhere far. Then we can't know what exactly get()
    # will return.
    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[str | list[str]], repeated: bool, **kwargs) -> None: ...
    
    def __init__(self, repeated: bool = False, **kwargs) -> None:
        self._repeated = repeated

    def get(self) -> _GetReturnT:
        if self._repeated:
            return ["Hello", "world!"]
        else:
            return "just one string"


default = StringProperty()  # StringProperty[str]
default_get = default.get()  # str

false_literal = StringProperty(repeated=False)  # StringProperty[str]
false_literal_get = false_literal.get()  # str

true_literal = StringProperty(repeated=True)  # StringProperty[list[str]]
true_literal_get = true_literal.get()  # list[str]

import random
some_bool = random.choice([True, False])  # bool
unknown_bool = StringProperty(repeated=some_bool)  # StringProperty[str | list[str]]
unknown_bool_get = unknown_bool.get()  # str | list[str]

reveal_locals()

# error: Value of type variable "_GetReturnT" of "StringProperty" cannot be "int"
#
# This error happens because we limited _GetReturnT's possible types in
# TypeVar(). If we didn't limit the types, users could accidentally refer to a
# type in an annotation that's impossible to instantiate.
def some_user_function(prop: StringProperty[int]) -> None:
    prop.get()
```

Note that setting and reading `self._repeated` does not aid in typing here in any way. `StringProperty` gets its type only from what types were passed to the constructor. If someone runs `false_literal._repeated = True`, then `false_literal.get()` would return `["Hello", "world!"]`, and the typing information is wrong.

Using `str` or `list[str]` for `StringProperty`'s type here was convenient. But the type can be less specific for weirder classes. Here we could've used `Literal[True]`, `Literal[False]`, and `Literal[True] | Literal[False]` to represent the quality of being repeated. Then `get()` would need overrides based on self to determine the return type.

```py
_T = TypeVar('_T',
    Literal["NOT_REPEATED"],
    Literal["REPEATED"],
    Literal[MyEnum.AMAZING],
    Literal[MyEnum.KINDA_OK_I_GUESS])

# For brevity I don't show Unions in this example, but you'd
# need them for a class that works properly.
class StringProperty(Generic[_T]):
    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[Literal["NOT_REPEATED"]],
        repeated: Literal[False]) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[Literal["REPEATED"]],
        repeated: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

    def __init__(self, repeated: bool) -> None:
        self._repeated = repeated

    @overload
    def get(self: StringProperty[Literal["NOT_REPEATED"]]) -> str: ...

    @overload
    def get(self: StringProperty[Literal["REPEATED"]]) -> list[str]: ...

    def get(self) -> str | list[str]:
        if self._repeated:
            return ["Hello", "world!"]
        else:
            return "just one string"
```

Comment: With python3.10 and mypy 0.991, your first example fails with:
`26: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[str]", expected "str")  [return-value]`
`28: error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "List[str]")  [return-value]`

Answer (score 0):

I also had to overload `get` in @Slix first example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, overload, Literal, Generic

_GetReturnT = TypeVar('_GetReturnT', str, list[str], str | list[str])

class StringProperty(Generic[_GetReturnT]):
    
    # Handles the default value case too.
    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[str], repeated: Literal[False]=False, **kwargs) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[list[str]], repeated: Literal[True], **kwargs) -> None: ...
    
    # Callers won't always pass a literal bool right at the call site. The bool
    # could come from somewhere far. Then we can't know what exactly get()
    # will return.
    @overload
    def __init__(self: StringProperty[str | list[str]], repeated: bool, **kwargs) -> None: ...
    
    def __init__(self, repeated: bool = False, **kwargs) -> None:
        self._repeated = repeated

    @overload
    def get(self: StringProperty[str]) -> str:
        ...

    @overload
    def get(self: StringProperty[list[str]]) -> list[str]:
        ...

    @overload
    def get(self: StringProperty[str | list[str]]) -> str | list[str]:
        ...

    def get(self) -> str | list[str]:
        if self._repeated:
            return ["Hello", "world!"]
        else:
            return "just one string"


default = StringProperty()  # StringProperty[str]
default_get = default.get()  # str

false_literal = StringProperty(repeated=False)  # StringProperty[str]
false_literal_get = false_literal.get()  # str

true_literal = StringProperty(repeated=True)  # StringProperty[list[str]]
true_literal_get = true_literal.get()  # list[str]

import random
some_bool = random.choice([True, False])  # bool
unknown_bool = StringProperty(repeated=some_bool)  # StringProperty[str | list[str]]
unknown_bool_get = unknown_bool.get()  # str | list[str]

reveal_locals()

# error: Value of type variable "_GetReturnT" of "StringProperty" cannot be "int"
#
# This error happens because we limited _GetReturnT's possible types in
# TypeVar(). If we didn't limit the types, users could accidentally refer to a
# type in an annotation that's impossible to instantiate.
def some_user_function(prop: StringProperty[int]) -> None:
    prop.get()
```

```
> venv/bin/mypy --version
mypy 0.991 (compiled: yes)
> venv/bin/mypy field.py
field.py:57: note: Revealed local types are:
field.py:57: note:     default: field.StringProperty[builtins.str]
field.py:57: note:     default_get: builtins.str
field.py:57: note:     false_literal: field.StringProperty[builtins.str]
field.py:57: note:     false_literal_get: builtins.str
field.py:57: note:     some_bool: builtins.bool
field.py:57: note:     true_literal: field.StringProperty[builtins.list[builtins.str]]
field.py:57: note:     true_literal_get: builtins.list[builtins.str]
field.py:57: note:     unknown_bool: field.StringProperty[Union[builtins.str, builtins.list[builtins.str]]]
field.py:57: note:     unknown_bool_get: Union[builtins.str, builtins.list[builtins.str]]
field.py:64: error: Value of type variable "_GetReturnT" of "StringProperty" cannot be "int"  [type-var]
field.py:65: error: Invalid self argument "StringProperty[int]" to attribute function "get" with type "Callable[[StringProperty[str]], str]"  [misc]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```